# Only one developer is getting push notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using APNS-Sharp to send push notifications.  Everything seems to be working fine for me, who has a developer provisioning profile.

I'm using a distribution profile for everyone else, and they are not getting push notifications.

My question is, does each provisioning profile have to be enabled for push notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are different push servers, one for development and one for production. Have you switched over to the appropriate server? gateway.push.apple.com:2195 and gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195.

Comment: Yes I have switched, but it won't connect on production.  I believe the issue is that only the developer can get push with the development cert.  In other words I am the only developer with a developer cert, the others are using distribution certs which requires production.  But I can't get production to work because it won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

Do all profiles and your dev and prod build have the same bundle identifier? Make sure the bundle id is correct and not a general bundle id.

Comment: Yes, they are not wildcard identifiers.